# How did Dillon die?

Tags: plot-explanation, killing-them-softly

In Killing them Softly at the end Brad Pitt says that Dillon died this morning:

> Dillon's dead now fucking pay me.

How did Dillon die? Did we watch it happen or no? I never really saw Dillon much in the film.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dillon has been unwell throughout the movie. Presumably in the hospital with a heart attack.  We first learn this when Brad Pitt's character, Jackie, first arrives and is having the conversation in the car with the Driver character.

> **Driver**: They told me when they heard that if Dillon wasn't available
>   that I was supposed to talk to the fella that he sent. Is that you?
>
> **Jackie**: I don't seen nobody else here. Do you?
>
> **Driver**: So they were very concerned when I called Dillon, and *Dillon said to see you. They are very concerned. How is the fella?*
>
> **Jackie**: *Ah he's not good. He told me yesterday that it feels like somebody stuck a knife through his chest.*
>
> **Driver**: *So he probably won't be able to handle anything for a while.*
>
> **Jackie**: *He sure cant' right now. Personally I think the guy is in very
>   bad shape.*

At the end of the movie, after Frankie, Russell, and Trattman have been hit, Jackie meets the Driver again in a bar to collect his payment.

> **Jackie**: There's only thirty in there....The price is fifteen.
>
> **Driver**: Dillon charges ten. Recession prices. They told me to tell you
>   that too.
>
> **Jackie**: They made a deal with Mickey for fifteen.
>
> **Driver**: ...you're filling in for Dillon and you get what Dillon gets, no more. You talk to Dillon; take it up with him.
>
> **Jackie**: *Dillon's dead. Dillon died this morning.*
>
> **Driver**: Ah, they're gonna be very sorry to hear that.
>
> **Jackie**: Sure. Sure they are. Its gonna cost em more.

**Whatever what causing him to be bed ridden this entire time has finally killed him.**

Comment: oh okay cool! I missed that initial conversation, thought Jackie and the Driver had a longer standing relationship